# Error: Getting symbols in python output

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, file-io, editor

```
#I wrote the following code for making a text editor.
print "This is a simple text editor"
from sys import argv
script, name = argv
print "You have selected the file : %s" %name
print "Opening the file...."
t = open(name, 'r+')
print "The contents of the file are" 
print t.read()
f = open(name, 'w+')
print "Now we will truncate the file and empty it of it's contents"
f.truncate()
print "Now let us write something into our file\n"
x = raw_input('What do you want to write\n') #Works fine till here
f.write(x)
print "Now we read our file again"
print f.read()
print "And finally we close the file"
f.close()
```

After the promp to write something in the file, the script goes awry and produces strange symbols instead of the typed text. Please help

Comment: Sorry, not psychic. Include input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close and re-open your file.

```
print "This is a simple text editor"
from sys import argv
script, name = argv
print "You have selected the file : %s" %name
print "Opening the file...."
t = open(name, 'r+')
print "The contents of the file are"
print t.read()
t.close()  ##########
f = open(name, 'w+')
print "Now we will truncate the file and empty it of it's contents"
f.truncate()
print "Now let us write something into our file\n"
x = raw_input('What do you want to write\n') #Works fine till here
f.write(x)
f.close()  ##########
f = open(name, 'r+')  ##########
print "Now we read our file again"
print f.read()
print "And finally we close the file"
f.close()
```

Comment: Silly of me. I am still a newbie so i keep making these silly mistakes. It works like a charm now